# add constraint to an empty scrollview on xib or storyboard ambiguity

Tags: ios, autolayout, scrollview, frame, xib

I added an **empty** scrollView on a view,set leading/top/trailing/bottom,then the frame is accurate，but when set leading/top/trailing/height,xib shows ambiguity error! if i set constraint by code ，it will be ok，why？？？is a bug of xib?[image: leading/top/trailing/trailing capture][image: leading/top/trailing/height capture]

Comment: I know how to clear error，just want to know the reason that  two case above lead to different result？

Answer (score 0):

Storyboard / Interface Builder is telling you that the scrollView has ***ambiguous content size*** because it has no contents.

You can either:

- ignore this "error" indicated in IB, or
- you can add a `UIView` as a subview of the scrollView (setting proper constraints), then at run-time either remove that view or add your UI elements to it (instead of adding to the scrollView directly).

As a side note... if your entire XIB file contains just a scroll view, don't do that. Just use a scroll view. If this is simply your first step, and you are going to be adding UI elements to the scroll view in the XIB as you proceed with your design process, then you will see the error go away as soon as you add elements and setup the proper constraints.

Comment: Thanks,I know how to do,but why? if set "leading/top/trailing/bottom",it has no contents either,but no error.

Comment: Interface Builder / Storyboard is not "run-time". It can only know what you've laid out, and the constraints you've set up. It has no way of knowing what you will do with that layout via code. In the case of a `UIScrollView`, IB is telling you the scrollView ***does not yet have*** constraints to determine the content size. That's why I say you can ignore the error / warning / information - *for that specific case* - if you know you'll be properly adding content at run-time.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a **view** to your **scrollView** and link them with leading/top/trailing/bottom constraints. Also you got to set **height/width** constraints to just added **view** to remove ambiguity.